# css three centered colums

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use bootstrap,css,and html to make a responsive webpage, which has three columns in a row. A textbox on the left, a button in the center, and a table on the right.

I've worked on trying to accomplish this three separate attempts: (to see code for the first attempt, open jsfiddle and ctrl+f: `<!-- output box 0 -->`)

https://jsfiddle.net/martinradio/adqLpxn5/57/

[image]

**I'm most keen on fixing attempt 1, since it has the best responsiveness when resizing the page to be very thin**

- Attempt 1
  Method based off [this](https://codepen.io/Cheesetoast/pen/KFAaq) example code, boxes work but are completely centered, I've been trying to change the width of the middle 'copy' box, if I can make the middle box smaller while keeping the responsiveness and the width of the outer boxes, it would work. I've tried setting the style of the middle box to have a width of 10%, but haven't been sucessfull.
- Attempt 2
  Raw bootstrap col and row divs, one row and three cols, left box was easy to set width:40,  but I couldn't style the middle copy button successfully.
- Attempt 3
  My original code, the tree boxes are finished versions of what I want the boxes to be, but I can't get it to be style responsively.

All three attempts are me trying to understand and complete a css task: **creating a responsive row containing three columns: col1 with a width of 45%, col2, with a width of 10%, and col3 with a width of 45%**

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have time to look at all of your attempts so I focused on attempt 2.

Here's why it doesn't work considering the requirement to have the 3 columns side by side:

- **Column 1, the `textarea`** is fine (although you don't need to set `cols="2"` because you're setting its width already). The textarea has the browser's default `display:inline` but due to some magic it behaves like `display:inline-block` considering its width.
- **Column 2, the `button`** is fine too (it has `display:inline-block` thanks to bootstrap)
- **Column 3, the `div`** has a browser-provided default of `display:block`. So it cannot be on the right of Column 2. You need to set `display: inline-block`. Also it has `width: 200%` but your requirement is 45% so this needs to be set accordingly.

### The inline & white space in HTML source problem

After you fix Column 3 like above, you will notice that the columns are still not side by side. Instead, Column 3 will still be on its own line even though their width percentages add up to 100%.

#### Why is this?

The reason is the white space between the columns in your HTML **source**. Inside a block context (which the containing div gives), any number of white space > 0 (including new lines) between inline tags will make the browser add one "space".

Example:

```
<div>
   <div style="display:inline-block">[one]</div>
   <div style="display:inline-block">[two]</div>
</div>
```

...results in:

```
[one] [two]
     ^
     note the space in between
```

...because, with the new line and the three spaces between the end tag of `div (one)` and the start tag of `div (two)`, there's a bunch of white space between the two inline-block elements in the HTML source.

#### How to solve this?

Two ways:

1. The obvious one: Remove the white space between the elements in the HTML source.
   That is, put the opening tag of each column immediately after the closing tag of the preceding column.
2. Set `font-size: 0` in the container element and set `font-size: <some-size>` for each column.
   This will give the "space" between the columns a width of 0.